# RPC:S-5:AEC-0 error on brand new tablets

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google play fails to install application with RPC:S-5:AEC-0](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33702/google-play-fails-to-install-application-with-rpcs-5aec-0)

I recently bought 2 of these [tablets](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0099NPR7U/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00), which had good reviews.

I bought them for my young daughters for Christmas. So, the tablets didn't have to be the best in the market. They need to be able to download games, but I am having problems with downloading from the Play Store.

The most frequent error is the RPC:S-5:AEC-0 error. All the fixes I have found for this are for problems following updates, and not for brand new devices. Nevertheless, I have tried clearing caches, re-installing GMail accounts, and restoring to factory settings but nothing is working.

The above link shows that the devices are on 4.0.3. But when I checked the tablets, they are on 4.0.4.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33702/22822)?