# Ridiculous error on all google play store Using CM 10.1.3

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I have a crazy problem. Whenever I update ***anything*** I get this error

> update for (insert Google app here) could not be downloaded due to an error (error while retrieving information from the server. [RPC:S-7:AEC-7 QNHM-TYSO-UNVHY])

It may also be worth telling you the very last 5 letters vary. It also happens to any new apps I attempt to install.

Comment: It might be an issue with your bank verifying your information electronically? Can you try purchasing with a different card/account? http://androidforums.com/android-applications/695478-play-store-error-rpc-s-7-aec-0-a.html  There's also this odd, arcane method of creating a new Google account and clearing the data cache for the play store: http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet/224884-google-play-error-solution-rpc-s-5-aec-0-a-5.html

Comment: No CM12 for your device? :-(

Comment: Samsung galaxy tab 2, so no :(

Comment: Other users: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34466/96277) was applicable in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to clear the cache of your Google services on the device. Note that this will remove your Google Account from the device - so you'll have to re-add it.

1. Navigate to `Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > All`
2. Clear the data for `Google Play Services`, `Google Service Framework` and `Google Play Store`
3. Reboot the device
4. Log back into your Google Account
5. Try your downloads again

Comment: OK. That has worked, and I'll mark you as the answer after you tell me why the only app with a problem is the store? I get instant "no connection" with WiFi on, even tho GH the hosts file is fine

Comment: After repeatedly trying your method, it worked! Marking as answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

This error can have multiple causes. Some are explained on our sister site, in [Error while retrieving information from the server RPC:s-7:AEC-0 in Google play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814958/error-while-retrieving-information-from-the-server-rpcs-7aec-0-in-google-play):

> turns out my credit card info on file needed updated to my new expiration date.

is one possibility. One more:

> RPC:AEC:0 error is known as CPU/RAM/Device/Identity failure.
>
> 1. Go to settings >application > Play Store >Clear Data & Clear Cache.
> 2. Go to accounts >Google >Remove account.
> 3. Reboot device.
> 4. Again Settings>Account >Google >Log In.

Another reason is explained on [AndroidPIT](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/504626/) (German): It could be problems with Google servers (same is, btw, reported by users in [this thread on AndroidForums.Com](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/695478-play-store-error-rpc-s-7-aec-0-a.html)). One user reported a work around that did it for him: He tried it at least 10 times on his Android device, without success. So he simply fired up the browser on his computer, and tried it from there -- which immediately worked.

For more details (and possible other solutions/work-arounds), just follow the other results from [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22RPC%3AS-7%3AAEC-0%22&ie=UTF-8).