# whenever I attempt to update or install an app I get and error

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I have been trying to update apps and install games for a month. I have looked all over for help. I was told to turn phone off and then back on and go to step two which didn't work.

The problem I'm having is that if I try to download or update any app I get this error message:

```
error retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-7:AEC-7 UTCK-S4PR-HINNC]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is installation failing from play store? Can you provide a screen shot and what is *step two*? Please edit your question and before that search if a similar question had been posted that may help

Comment: Also add your device , OS and play store version

Comment: Please read again and post all relevant details **in the question by editing**. Have you searched as advised, if a similar question had been posted (which I am pretty sure has been asked earlier)

Comment: Related: [Error while buying apps in Google Play store in Android Jelly Bean](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44873/16575) (RPC:S-7:AEC-0; [several more of those at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RPC%3AS-7%3AAEC-7)). How-to on the exact error [at Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IujFpuP3NE), and [more to find with a simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="RPC%3AS-7%3AAEC-7") – so obviously you haven't "looked all over" ;)

Comment: And here's the question @beeshyams was referring to: [Ridiculous error on all google play store Using CM 10.1.3](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115592/16575) (`[RPC:S-7:AEC-7 QNHM-TYSO-UNVHY]`; error codes list in our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) updated).

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up. I read this little post on XDA and another [user's resolution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/error-rpcs-7aec-7-t2899230) was:

> -Go to Settings->Applications->Manage Applications->All
>   -Select "Clear Data" for Google Play Services and Google Service Framework
>   -Reboot the device

This would be a good first start. I did some more digging (as I am unable to recreate the fault) and found it also appears necessary to [remove your Google Account and re-add it to your device](http://www.fixerrs.com/2015/02/error-retrieving-information-from-server-rpc-s-7-aec-7.html), so this may also be a good shot.

If this is a dire circumstance (and you cannot format your phone or perform a system update), [you can enable unknown sources](http://www.androidcentral.com/allow-app-installs-unknown-sources) and find the APK you need - this should install.

Lastly, here is a nice little [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85p0my2lWTI) to help demonstrate what you need to do.