# Unable to purchase apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I am new to Android but have got a new phone running 5.0.1 using my Gmail account administered by my university in New Zealand. However I am unable to purchase apps in the Google Play store. I am able to download free ones but no any for which I have to pay money. Instead I get an error which says

Error while retrieving information from server[RPC:S-7:AEC-0 ...]
The ... is a 13 letter code in the format XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX which seems to change everytime I try.

I have tried restarting, updateing,  clearing the cache of the play store, Download Manager, Google play services and have added and removed my primary gmail account and done the same. I have done everything suggested here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/4592924

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! While waiting for answers, you might wish to take a look into our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info), which lists most errors and links to possible solutions. I couldn't find yours exactly by your description; [Google play fails to install application with RPC:S-5:AEC-0](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33702/16575) sounds pretty similar from the error code, but doesn't seem to be exactly the same.

Comment: Just wondering, Can you purchase apps from the play store via a desktop/laptop?

Comment: This answer was applicable in my case: [Google play fails to install application with RPC:S-5:AEC-0](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34466)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted on the [Google play store forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/D9bvX_gwga4;context-place=topicsearchin/play/unable$20to$20purchase$20apps) and Byteguy posted suggested that my university was likely blocking purchases. This had not occured to me and sure enough when I set up a new Google account things worked fine.