# Google Play Music : Error retrieving information from server [RPC:S-7:AEC-0 xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx]

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google, google-play-music

When trying to subscribe to the trial of Google Play Music, I came accross this error.

I *had 2 accounts (removed secondly account while trying to resolve issue), primary is the only one active.

This account has a Card attached for purchasing,  which I use often. This card  appears in my Google Wallet.

**What I have tried:**

1. Clear data from :

   - Google Services Framework
   - Google Play Store
2. Uninstalled Google Play music
3. Removed(primary and secondary accounts)
4. Also removed card from Google Wallet

After each step except from data clearing which was done altogether, a reboot was done.

Any other possible solutions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to purchase apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/unable-to-purchase-apps). Some other related questions might also be able to help out. http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=RPC%3AS-7%3AAEC

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I already checked, the application is not the same and the OS version is different too

Comment: I found that Google Play Music was extraordinarily buggy.  Sometimes it would work, sometimes errors like the one you experienced would appear.  There seemed to be no rhyme or reason to it.  I decided it wasn't worth the frustration.

Comment: I also can't subscribe for the trail. Same error code. Didn't find a solution though. http://imgur.com/jt3uCfn

Comment: I can purchase apps from Google Play, but not Google Play Music.